# FormData.append() is empty iterating over a FileList

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have difficulty figuring out why `formData` is returning an empty object when iterating over a list of files and appending them to an empty instance `FormData()` using `formData.append()`.

MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

---

component.html

```html
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" multiple accept="image/*" (change)="onImageSelect($event)"/>
```

component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-uploader',
  templateUrl: './image-uploader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-uploader.component.css']
})
export class ImageUploaderComponent {
  fileList: File[] = [];

  onImageSelect(files: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    this.fileList = files.target.files;

    for (const file of this.fileList) {
      formData.append('images[]', file, file.name);
      console.log(file, file.name);
    }
    console.log(formData); // returns an empty {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I think when iterating over an array you should use `for (const file in this.fileList)`

Comment: I can't get it working using for...in. 

And funny enough although FileList is an Object and iterate over it using for...of and `console log(file, file.name) ` as the example above it logs what I think I need. A File object, the the File.name. 

I'm confused 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always prefer typed alternatives. In this case you could use

```
<input #filePicker type="file" ... (change)="onImageSelect(filePicker.files)" />
```

And then, in the *Component* class

```
onImageSelect(files: FileList): void {
  ...

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];
    formData.append('images[]', file, file.name);
  }
}
```

That's it.
Remember you cannot loop a `FileList` with a `for-of` as it lacks the *Iterator Symbol*.

Comment: Right. And you can't `console.log(formData)` you have to `console.log(formData.getAll('images[]')`